# Derived Classes Cannot Access Private Members

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

In C++:
The concept is derived class objects and member functions cannot access the private members of the parent class. But what if a public member function of the Parent class returns the reference of the private variable and the Parent class is publicly inherited in the child class and child class has a function(in this case display()) which calls the function from the parent class (in this case show()) and takes the reference of the private variable x. The address of a should match x but I don't why it is different?

```
enter code here

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class test{
    int x=10;
    public:
    int & show();
};
class ChildTest: public test{
    public:
    void display(){
        int a=show();
        cout<<&a<<endl;
    }
};
int & test::show(){
    cout<<&x<<endl; //so this address should match the above address but it //is not matching I don't understand why?
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    ChildTest obj;
    obj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
0x7ffe5b751bb0
0x7ffe5b751bb4

I don't understand what is the concept running behind the change of address, given that I am passing a reference to the private variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here you just display address of local variable `a` (which has the value of `test::x`)

Change to `int& a=show();` to have same address displayed.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42. So via this way, we can access and change the private variable from any class. Even if the variable is private, right?

Comment: @amitpandey - Yes. The `private` keyword only affects the accessibility of the name. It has no effect on the storage to which the name refers.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
int a = show();
```

you're saying "make a brand new integer variable named `a`, and initialize it using the return value of `show()`. Even though `show` returns an `int &`, since you've explicitly said "I'd like a new `int`," C++ creates a copy of the value stored in the `int` referred to by the return of `show()`.

To fix this, change your code to read

```
int& a = show();
```

This says "create a new `int` reference and have it bind to whatever the reference returned by `show()` refers to." That way, no copies of integers are made, and you should see the same address

Note that this has nothing to do with inheritance. It's purely a function of copying an `int` versus storing a reference.

Comment: What happens if `show()` doesn't return a reference?

Comment: @Omnifarious Hoo boy, then you're in trouble if you store a non-`const` reference to it, since then you have a dangling reference. But, then again, I don' think the OP would be surprised in that case to see different addresses, since they've explicitly opted to return a copy of the original value.

Comment: Actually, no, `display()` would run just fine and is guaranteed to run just fine in the case where `show()` returns an `int` (not an `int &`). Now, if display tried to return its reference, that's where the trouble begins. If you explicitly create a named reference to a temporary, that temporary is guaranteed to hang around for the life of that name. Just try to help you improve your answer. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious I think I'm missing something here. I thought the OP's concern was that the address printed in `display` didn't match the address printed in `show`. If `show` returns its result by value, then `display` would have to print out an address that didn't match `show` because the `int` it's displaying is a different `int` value. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting what you're hinting at, though.

Comment: You answered the OPs question just fine. I was thinking you had phrased one sentence about the return value of show in a way that talked about binding references to return values in general. But on re-reading I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is a value. If, for instance, you used a custom class instead of an integer, you would get the same address. However, being a value type, all Integer variables hold their own separate space in memory. To have the same address, your variable `a` should be changed to a pointer to a Integer value :

```
    void display() {
        int* a=show();
        cout<<a<<endl;
    }
```

With that change, the addresses should be the same.Note that I removed the `&` in the output. That is because the variable `a` is now pointing to the address of the value. To use the value, call with `*a`.

Source (https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson6.html):

> Pointing to Something: Retrieving an Address
>
> In order to have a pointer actually point to another variable it is
>   necessary to have the memory address of that variable also. To get the
>   memory address of a variable (its location in memory), put the & sign
>   in front of the variable name. This makes it give its address. This is
>   called the address-of operator, because it returns the memory address.
>   Conveniently, both ampersand and address-of start with a; that's a
>   useful way to remember that you use & to get the address of a
>   variable.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>    #include <iostream>
>
>    using namespace std;
>
>    int main() {
>        int x;    // A normal integer   
>        int *p;   // A pointer to an integer
>
>        p = &x;           // Read it, "assign the address of x to p"   
>        cin>>x;          // Put a value in x, we could also use *p here  
>        cin.ignore();   
>        cout<< *p <<"\n"; // Note the use of the * to get the value  
>        cin.get(); 
>    }
> ```

EDIT : Had a mistake, and someone else answered while I wrote this.

Comment: You've still got a `*a`. :-)

Comment: Actually, I'll update with a source about how to use pointers in a bit.